# inspecting the war file from inside after I have deployed the war file at google appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, war

After I have deployed my application on google app engine,is there a method I can see inside the folder present in the war. I have to check if a *file* is uploaded there. I mean can i inspect the war file from inside. I can do this with *winrar* while there on my hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can read the files of your application after deploying the project to Google App Engine.

As use are using java-ee in your project, you can make use of the **AppEngineFile** class.
See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/files/AppEngineFile)